# Ударение в слове "мирячение"

Tags: фонетика

Я всегда считал, что ударение в слове "мирячение" (массовый психоз, наблюдаемый среди северных народов) падает на Я, а вчера в передаче услышал "мирячЕние". А как все- таки правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда считал, что спрашивать про слово надо у тех, кто его знает.
Слово не фиксируется общелитературными словарями, а во всяких специальных изданиях ударение не проставлено.
На слух "мерЯченье", конечно, лучше, но...